# How to plot contour plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, contour

How to plot like this in MATLAB

[image]

I have tried this, but didn't find desired result

```
X = 1.2:0.2:3;
Y = 3:0.2:4;

[x, y] = meshgrid(X, Y);
z = x.*y;
contourf(x, y, z, 'ShowText', 'on');

colorbar

title ('Power Efficient Conversion (PEC) Bulk Heterojunction of Solar Cell');
xlabel ('Band Gap [donor]');
ylabel ('LUMO [donor]');
```

Comment: What is the result, how does it differ with what you want to get? Knowing that makes it easier to help you, we’re not going to be running your code just to see what it does… Also, did you read the documentation for `contourf`? MATLAB documentation is really good, and always has plenty of examples to start from.

Comment: `I have tried this, but didn't find desired result` What is the problem ? Your contour is pretty close (i.stack.imgur.com/2bHUD.png), only the colorscale differs, and your separator line are black instead of white. Is it that ? You need to clarify your problem